# N-Tier Architecture Layer Naming Suggestions

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, n-tier-architecture

I am looking to reorganize my backend n-tier application to break up the layers so that they are more independent and testable. I will have the following layers.

```
 Entities
 Data Access Layer
 Business Logic
 Contracts
 Service
```

Is there any best practices for naming these layers?

Comment: You just named them.  Congrats.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is a matter of preference, but i would go with something like:

- CompanyName.ApplicationName.Data
- CompanyName.ApplicationName.Data.DataAccess
- CompanyName.ApplicationName.BusinessLayer
- CompanyName.Common.Contracts
- CompanyName.Common.Services

Using "Common" where the library will be shared, and "ApplicationName", where they are specific to a single application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Would Data.EntityFramework be to specific for the DataAccess layer?

Comment: @mflair2000 for me, it would be too specific. Anything using that library doesn't need to know you are using EF, and you may at a later date wish to use something else for data access. Your name would then not make any sense.